# Ubuntu media folder contains names of directories that are no longer present

Tags: partitioning, mount, storage

After doing some reformatting & renaming of specific partitions on my Ubuntu installation, I see that in the `/media` folder there is still a directory with the old label volume (and also another directory with the new label of the volume).

What is a safe way for me to remove the old labelled folder which is no longer a relevant path?

Comment: It should be empty, so `rmdir` should work safely.

Comment: Even safer: rename it to FormerName_bak and leave it for a week, then delete it if all is well...